# Python "in" operator speed

Tags: python, time, size, in-operator

Is the `in` operator's speed in python proportional to the length of the iterable?

So,

```
len(x) #10
if(a in x): #lets say this takes time A
    pass

len(y) #10000
if(a in y): #lets say this takes time B
    pass
```

Is A > B?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A summary for in:

```
list - Average: O(n)
set/dict - Average: O(1), Worst: O(n)
```

See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more details.

Comment: so if i need to check if a string is present as a key in a dict. then it will take O(1). but if i need to see if a string is present in a list then O(n) right?

Comment: or even if i have a set of string and a list of string, x in set will be faster than x in list right?

Comment: when can the worst case occur?

Comment: I think when all the keys have the same hash value in the dict

Comment: in a set? how does that happen?

Comment: dicts and sets have very similar implementations in CPython - they're both based on hash codes.  Worst-case behavior has *never* been seen outside of code deliberately designed to provoke it - but you need some rational faith in statistics ;-)  If you *want* to provoke it, then, e.g., define your own class with a `__hash__` method that returns a constant.

Comment: I had not thought about that worst case scenario when I opened this thread so seeing O(n) was a surprise. Interesting to know!

Answer (score 8):

There's no general answer to this:  it depends on the types of `a` and especially of `b`.  If, for example, `b` is a list, then yes, `in` takes worst-case time `O(len(b))`.  But if, for example, `b` is a dict or a set, then `in` takes expected-case time `O(1)` (i.e., constant time).

About "Is A > B?", you didn't define `A` or `B`.  As above, there's no general answer to which of your `in` statements will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` and `y` are `lists`:

> Is the `in` operator's speed in Python proportional to the length of the iterable?

Yes.

The time for `in` to run on a `list` of length `n` is `O(n)`. It should be noted that it is `O(1)` for `x in set` and `x in dict` as they are hashed, and `in` is constant time.

---

> Is A > B?

No.

Time `A` < Time `B` as `10 < 10000`

---

> Docs: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity